# Erase blank rows while reading csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have tried to delete blank rows from my cvs file, however this is not working, it only writes out the first line

please take a look and tell me how i can get all the rows with text and skip the rows that are blank

Here is the code:
[image: file]
 I  just reads out the first line of the csv file

Thank you in advance!

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: `df.read_csv(...).dropna()`

Comment: Hmmm, blanks rows are omitted by default.

Answer (score 6):

First read your csv file with pandas with

```
df=pd.read_csv('input.csv')
```

then remove blank rows,

```
df=df.dropna()
```

For more details in dropna, check the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas-dataframe-dropna).

Comment: Is there any way to optimize the row deleting part? I need this treatment for very large csv files (70Go..)

Comment: @SamadiSalahedine- dropna is efficient way of dropping nan rows. If your file size is large which can't handle by pandas easily then I suggest you to use dask. For more details follow this http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.dropna

Answer (score 2):

There is problem:

```
for line in df:
    print (line)
```

return columns names.

Answer (score 2):

If I have a csv file like below with blank row

```
B;D;K;N;M;R 

0;2017-04-27 01:35:30;C;3.5;A;01:15:00;23.0 
1;2017-04-27 01:37:30;B;3.5;B;01:13:00;24.0 


2;2017-04-27 01:39:00;K;3.5;C;00:02:00;99.0




4;2017-04-27 01:39:00;K;3.5;C;00:02:00;99.0
```

`df = pd.read_csv('input.csv',delimiter=';')` will give the dataframe ignoring the blank lines.

```
                     B  D    K  N         M    R 
0  2017-04-27 01:35:30  C  3.5  A  01:15:00  23.0
1  2017-04-27 01:37:30  B  3.5  B  01:13:00  24.0
2  2017-04-27 01:39:00  K  3.5  C  00:02:00  99.0
4  2017-04-27 01:39:00  K  3.5  C  00:02:00  99.0
```

Your code works when you use `open`. Pandas read_csv will convert the csv file into dataframe. You might be confused with one another.

```
df = open('input.csv')
new_contents = []
for line in df:
    if not line.strip():
        continue 
    else: 
        new_contents.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the latest pandas (v 1.3.0), there is an argument where you can tell it to skip blank rows. It's enabled by default, but if you want to make it True anyway (e.g. self-documenting code), just set that flag to True. This is from the doc:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

**skip_blank_lines**: *bool, default True*

       If True, skip over blank lines rather than interpreting as NaN values.

So, in your code it is:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep = ';', skip_blank_lines=True)
```